# What is the proof of this sentence?

Tags: analysis

My only question is about this.
I couldn't find it and I need help with it because I can't find it in any of my books.
Here is the sentence that I need the proof of:

> $$
> \Biggl[ \frac{[x]}{n} \Biggr]
> =\left[ \frac{x}{n} \right]
> $$
>   where $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}^*$ and $[ x ]$ is the integer part of $x$.

Comment: What do the brackets mean?

Comment: It is the 
integer part

Answer (score 1):

Let $k=\biggl\lfloor\dfrac x n\biggr\rfloor$. This means that
$$k\le \frac xn<k+1\iff nk\le x<n(k+1)$$
This implies that $\lfloor x\rfloor\ge nk$, so $\;\dfrac{\lfloor x\rfloor}n \ge k $ and ultimately $\;\biggl\lfloor\dfrac{\lfloor x \rfloor}n \biggr\rfloor\ge k$.

The reverse inequality results from the integer part function being non-decreasing:

$\lfloor x\rfloor\le x$, hence $\;\dfrac{\lfloor x\rfloor}n\le\dfrac xn$, hence …

Comment: I believe my edit to the question is not helpful. Please revert to previous.

Comment: @DanielMathias I've reverted to the $[x]$ notation + added the definition into the post

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=an+b$ where $a$ is an integer and $0\le b <n$. Then $\lfloor\frac{x}{n}\rfloor=a$.

We also have $\lfloor x\rfloor=an+\lfloor b \rfloor$ where  $0\le \lfloor b \rfloor<n$. Therefore $\lfloor\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{n}\rfloor=a.
$